# Sonata get the form request?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I have the Sonata bundle and I got the form to create a new database entry.
As soon as I click the save button, the bundle is processing everything.

But for example I need a random string for a key. How can I process that key? Do I need to create a Controller between the form and processing? How can I override the default upload method?

```
$this->get('request')
```

isn't useable in my Adminclass.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [sonata easy-extends](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/2-x/doc/index.html)

Once installed you should be able to override Sonata behviour easily